# Authenticated users on tool to access SQL Server database with specific permissions

Tags: sql-server, frontend, database-administration

Looking for recommendations on best practice when it comes to SQL Server users and permissions.
For context, I have a web based intranet based tool where users can log in. Within this tool there is a section where users can run free text SQL Queries against the database with the intention of selection specific data.

Currently all users can access all data because the tool itself has a dedicated user. Moving forwards, permissions of data will depend on the user that is logged in to the web tool, this will control database tables (and even rows) they should have access to, so if they try access a table they shouldn't have access to they will be rejected

Currently running SQL Server 2022
Authentication to tool through LDAP

I am currently floating around 2 solutions for this problem which both involve each connection having linked to a specific user with specific permissions.

Solution 1:
Login/User created with Unique name dynamically at the time a query is executed and select permissions are granted based on what the user should have access to (everything else is revoked by default)
Login/User gets dropped from database when query finishes

Solution 2:
Login/User created with name same as the authenticated user on the web tool. At the time a query is executed the permissions will be checked on the database and revoked/added as required (these permissions will not change very often)

Things to consider

- Users will be allowed to run multiple queries at once, as some of these queries can take a very long time to complete (just the nature of the task)
- Many users will execute many queries simultaneously

One of the most notable benefits of solution 1 is that the Password does not need to be stored anywhere as the user is simply disposed of after every execution

Looking for recommendations on solutions, even ones I haven't considered here

Comment: Unfortunately this sort of question is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: But I can tell you one thing for free, best practice is to *never*, let *anyone* run raw SQL though a web UI.

Comment: i would probably do something like this: 1) for each web user create a corresponding db user 2) use that db user's credentials when running queries 3) if you have some standard rights which most users are fine with, you can create some standard user that one gets by default

Answer (score 0):

Do Solution 1, except create the SQL Server database user for each end user without a password.

```
create user Alice without login
```

Then connect from your app as a privileged user and impersonate the end user when running the queries with [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
execute as user='Alice'
```

That connection will remain impersonated until you REVERT, close the connection, or check it into the .NET connection pool (YMMV with other connection pool implementations).

Comment: Thanks David, I hadn't thought about using execute as!
This is a fantastic idea, one limitation I can think of is that in some cases the queries will go across multiple databases. So that might be a limitation of a user without login. Unless you can think of a way around it